# Loading Executables Without Executing

Tags: process, module

Today I came observed the Windows Explorer process loading another PE executable file but there was no subsequent process launch. The only explanations I could find were in regards to DLL executables behaving this way so that the loading process could use functions.

I have noticed Explorer doing this with programs such as Internet Explorer, additional Explorer processes and rundll32.exe.

What would cause a process to load a module but then not actually execute the module to create a new process? Why does this type of activity occur?

Comment: Read the documentation for [LoadLibraryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), particularly the possible flags that can be used. RunDLL32 is a special case; it's entire purpose is to allow you to run certain Control Panel functionality from the command line, which normally isn't possible. Read the documentation for it (available at MSDN as well).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that the activity can occur and it is completely acceptable as I previously read documentation for the LoadLibrary function. I do not understand the purpose behind loading a module that is unrelated to the process without actually running it however. A handle to the address location is returned but it appears that it is never used.

Comment: You apparently missed the part about loading for resources only, which can include resources (such as icons) stored in executables (and thus my mention to look at the flag values). Retrieving resources does not *actually run* anything. I can load *Notepad++.exe* from *MyApp.exe* to retrieve an icon without executing *Notepad++.exe* using `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`.

Comment: Thank you. That makes it a bit more clear in addition to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141120-00/?p=43573